# CSS/jQuery Spacing Issue

Tags: css

Im developing a site and for the life of me I cant get rid of the white space that sits below my jQuery slider on the page listed below. The "grey borders" to the left and right extend down based on a defined height. But the double black line divider that separates the page has white space above it. I've been trying everything with no luck.

http://www.celebrationandhope.org/

Comment: In Safari, I'm not seeing anything that looks like a _"double black line divider"_ on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

For your `main-slider` your are using a repeatable image with 2 lines (top and bottom). The height of this block is fixed in css - 363px which is much more than your `slider` - 309px.

[image]

So, to fix it you need to get smaller background with lines and decrease height of `main-slider` or increase the height of your slider to fit container.

Comment: thanks for the help on this everyone. im going to continue working on that. on the same page im also trying to set the jquery slideshow to scroll 4 photos when the user uses the red arrow buttons. right now they scroll at 1 slide. still new to this jquery stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
#main-slider {
background: url("images/main-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 360px; <!-- also edited -->
padding-top: 6px; <!-- set to 6px -->
}
```

Makes the white space disappear. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the height of the container element "main-slider" to a specific value and the content isn't filling it up all the way.